# Display empty editor for default values using EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My model has a property:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

which I'm displaying in my (strongly typed) view using EditorFor:

```
<p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BirthDate)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthDate)
</p>
```

When the view is rendered the birth date textbox shows "01.01.0001", i.e. the DateTime default value. This is correct if the BirthDate value is not initialized, however I want the textbox to be empty in that case.

What is the standard way to do this? I don't want to use Nullable<DateTime> in my model because BirthDate is a required value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DisplayFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute most likely. Also, unless you're using a `DateTime?`/`Nullable<DateTime>` you're probably going to end up with Jan 1 (since there can't be a null value).

If you do decide to use `DateTime?`/`Nullable<DateTime>` enforcing a value using `[Required]` should avoid any issues you're speaking of, so if that was your hesitation I wouldn't be too worried.

As a final alternative, you can override the `DateTime.cshtml` (or `Date.cshtml` since you're using the `DataType` attribtue) template (~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/) and make the textbox empty when populated with `default(DateTime)`. e.g.

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox(String.Empty, Model == default(DateTime) ? String.Empty : Model)
```

(Or something along those lines)

Comment: DisplayFormat doesn't help because I can't define a format to display "nothing", and I'd rather not use a Nullable because changing the business objects to accomodate View functionality doesn't feel like clean separation of concerns. The template (placed in ~/Shared/EditorTemplates) however does excactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @matk: keep in mind that business objects (like POCOs) are usually kept server-side and VMs are used to display (then using something like AutoMapper makes it easier to marry the two). With that said, making a VM have a nullable property isn't all that bad as it will just end up populating the POCO in your action, while keeping the look and feel within the UI.

Comment: True, _if_ a ViewModel is used. I like the template based approach better because it will take care of all instances where a DateTime is displayed, whether a ViewModel is used or not.